# how to add time picker using react materialize?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react materialize time picker

and I am getting this error:
[image: error image]

> `TypeError: $(...).pickatime is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [github comment](https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues/438#issuecomment-372947303)

> pickatime doesn't work with certain version of materialize-css

Update materialize-css version accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Visit this link https://react-materialize.github.io/#/forms.

Goto View page source from that page.Copy the materialize.js and main.css link and replace it in index.html from public folder from your react project.

Open main.css link and copy entire code and make new file(main.css) in your public folder and paste the code there. It worked for me hope it works for you.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, it prevents your answer from being searchable and is a pain if people want to copy and paste sections into their own projects. Additionally, this doesn't really seem to be an answer to the question so much as a slightly hacky workaround. It would be better to explain the cause of the OPs problem, and why using this solution fixes it.